# How to change xticklables from pandas plot with timedelta x-axis?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, timedelta

I am trying to plot this dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataFrame({'d': [np.timedelta64(5,'h'), np.timedelta64(7,'h')],
                 'v': [100,200]})

ax = df.set_index('d').plot.bar()
```

Which looks like this:
[image]

Here, I would like to remove "days 0 " from the xticklabels.

Here is my attempt:

```
ax = df.set_index('d').plot.bar()
locs, labels = plt.xticks()

for l in labels:
    print(l)

# gives
Text(0, 0, '0 days 05:00:00')
Text(0, 0, '0 days 07:00:00')
```

Also,

```
xlabels = [l for l in ax.get_xticklabels()]
# [Text(0, 0, '0 days 05:00:00'), Text(1, 0, '0 days 07:00:00')]
```

But when I try to change:
`xlabels[0][2] = str(xlabels[0][2]).lstrip('days 0` ')

I get following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-2e745c3160f9> in <module>()
----> 1 lst[0][2]

TypeError: 'Text' object does not support indexing
```

How to fix the error? or as a whole, how to change the xticklables in this plot?

Comment: A single line: `ax.set_xticklabels([l.get_text().split()[-1] for l in ax.get_xticklabels()])`

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solves the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import text as TEXT


df = pd.DataFrame({'d': [np.timedelta64(5,'h'), np.timedelta64(7,'h')],
                 'v': [100,200]})


ax = df.set_index('d').plot.bar()
xlabels = [l for l in ax.get_xticklabels()]

newlabels = []
for xlabel in xlabels:
    x,y = xlabel.get_position();
    lbl = xlabel.get_text().lstrip('0 days ');
    text = TEXT(x, y, lbl,visible=False);
    newlabels.append(text)

ax.set_xticklabels(newlabels)
```

## output

[image]